# Python print different output if change order of if else

Tags: python

I just a beginner in Python and today i see something strange with my if else output. I have following code:

```
for number in range(1, 100):
    if(number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0): ##this line now use first and output print correctly
        print("FizzBuzz") 
    elif(number % 3 == 0):
        print("Fizz")
    elif(number % 5 == 0):
        print("Buzz")
    else:
        print(number)
```

Above code print correctly, but if i change order of if else like this:

```
for number in range(1, 100):
    if(number % 3 == 0):
        print("Fizz")
    elif(number % 5 == 0):
        print("Buzz")
    elif(number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0): #this line not use first and output never have "fizzbuzz"
        print("FizzBuzz")
    else:
        print(number)
```

Then the output will not print "Fizzbuzz" even loop until 15 or 30 or any number multiples of both 3 and 5
What going on, please help, thanks a lots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the the code start checking from the `if` part and then goes further `elif` parts if the previous one is `false`.

Basically, the number which is divisible by both `3` and `5` will meet the first `if` logic as it is divisible by `3` also in your second code, so it will execute that `if` and won't go further.

Here this code will execute like :

1. first it will check `if(number%3 == 0)`, if it is true then it will `print("Fizz")` and rest of the `elif` and `else` will not be checked.
2. If `1` is not true then it will check `elif(number%5 == 0)`
3. Then by this way it will go down.

```
if(number % 3 == 0):
        print("Fizz")
    elif(number % 5 == 0):
        print("Buzz")
    elif(number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0): #this line not use first and output never have "fizzbuzz"
        print("FizzBuzz")
    else:
        print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to test the most inclusive statement first. Let's walk through an an example for this code:

```py
for number in range(1, 100):
    if(number % 3 == 0):
        print("Fizz")
    elif(number % 5 == 0):
        print("Buzz")
    elif(number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0): #this line not use first and output never have "fizzbuzz"
        print("FizzBuzz")
    else:
        print(number)
```

`number==3`

```py
if(number % 3 == 0): # 3 % 3 == 0, evaluates as True
    print("Fizz")
```

The rest of your `elif` statements will not run. They only run if the `if` or `elif` statements above them return `False`

Same is true for all multiples of 3 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single `if` statement with multiple conditions, which are checked from top to bottom. Once *one* condition is true, none of the rest are checked. If `number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0` would be true, then it is guaranteed that either `number % 3 == 0` or `number % 5 == 0` is true as well, so the FizzBuzz case is never reached.